# Вывод строки в заданном порядке через рекурсию

Tags: java, рекурсия

Было задание написать функцию, которая через рекурсию выводит в формате "символ-символ-символ". Например есть строка "Hello", то рекурсивный метод должен вернуть "H-e-l-l-o". Вот мой код

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println(foo("Hello World!!"));

}


public static String foo(String s) {
    String result ="";
    if (s.isEmpty()) 
        return "";
    if (result.endsWith("-")) return "";
    else {
        char firstChar = s.charAt(0);
        String nextChar = foo(s.substring(1));

        if(firstChar == s.charAt(s.length() - 1)) 
            return firstChar + "";
        else
            return result = firstChar + "-" + nextChar;
    }
```

Мой код работает. Но... Если использовать строку "!!!" в качестве параметра, то в результате функция вернет "!". Проблема в строке

```
if(firstChar == s.charAt(s.length() - 1)) 
    return firstChar + "";
```

Но я не знаю, как иначе переписать. Очень надеюсь на Вашу помощь. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное, нужно как-то так:

```
public static String foo(String s) {
    if (s.isEmpty()) {
        return "";
    }
    char firstChar = s.charAt(0);
    String nextChar = foo(s.substring(1));

    if (s.length()==1) 
        return firstChar + "";
    else
        return firstChar + "-" + nextChar;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для вашего подхода к решению задания вполне достаточно одного предложения в теле функции:

```
public static String foo( String s ) 
{
    return s.length() < 2 ? s : s.charAt( 0 ) + "-" + foo( s.substring( 1 ) );
}
```

Comment: Поменяйте только `length` на `length()`, а `s[0]` на `s.charAt(0)`.

Comment: @LEQADA А в Java нет оператора индексирования для строк?

Comment: Ну, на самом деле, внутри `String` сидит `char[]`, но он `private`, поэтому вы не можете так просто пройтись по нему. Нужно использовать методы.